# Why is Visual Studio 2022 crashing when attempting to reload projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with multiple projects.
The projects are a mix of loaded/unloaded in the solution.
When I attempt to reload any projects in Visual Studio, it crashes.
I've tried all combinations, including "Reload all projects."

How do I fix this issue?
Are there potentially some corrupt user files that I can clean up?

Comment: Have you tried repairing VS, just in case that is where the problem is? In Visual Studio Installer, click the "More" button.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I just did an update and the same issue. I'm not sure what you mean by the "more" button. VS just crashes with no tombstone or warning dialog. To me this feels like some user data that might have been corrupted? How do I get back to ground zero and have all projects loaded?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Figured out the issue. The info is stored in the .suo file. That file is no longer in the same folder as the solution file (.sln). It now resides in the (hidden) .vs folder in either V16 or V17 subfolder. Deleting the file took care of the issue. Thanks for making things more difficult Microsoft....

Comment: That sounds like it would be good to write as an answer.

Comment: I've also been getting crashes in various scenarios since updating to VS17.6.1, looking in the Event Logs might show more details of the cause of the crash. Deleting the .vs also fixed the problems I had. @JohnB This would probably be worth raising as a bug on the [MS Visual Studio Developer Community Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home)